# Gelfond-Schneider transcendental Kuzmin

Tags: transcendental-numbers

The so-called Gelfond-Schneider constant $2^\sqrt{2}$ is transcendental, as shown by Kuzmin (1930).

What can you say about its square root? Is it also transcendental?

Comment: square roots of transcendentals are very likely to be transcendentals too.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown they must be transcendental indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Its square root $2^{\sqrt2/2}$ satisfies the same criteria as stated in [Gelfond–Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem), so it is transcendental.

---

Or as someone pointed out in a comment, square roots of transcendental numbers are transcendental:

Let $p(\sqrt x) =0 $ for some polynomial $p \in \Bbb Q[X]$.

Then, $p(\sqrt x) p(-\sqrt x)$ is a polynomial in $x$. Denote it by $q \in \Bbb Q[X]$.

Then, $q(x) = 0$.